# Why hadoop format give out "java.net.UnknownHostException" exception

Tags: hadoop, configuration, localhost

I'm learning hadoop and try to set up the environment according to online documents.
I've configured the ssh (that ssh localhost won't need a password), configured the 
"core-site.xml", "hdfs-site.xml", "mapred-site.xml" and "yarn-site.xml"
But when I tried "hadoop namenode -format" it gave out "java.net.UnknownHostException" and 
host = java.net.UnknownHostException:

I've tried to search online help but nearly all are: change the network configuration in etc/hosts. But I'm using hadoop 2.4 and there's no such folder.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, they are right, you have to change the /etc/hosts file. I assume you have localhost on your hadoop configuration files, so you need to open /etc/hosts as sudo and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost
```

Comment: But I don't have the /etc/hosts directory or files.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: yeah, I did that. But the only content inside is: "127.0.0.1 localhost"
"255.255.255.255 broadcasthost"
"::1             localhost" 
"fe80::1%lo0 localhost" and not sure where I can change the thing

Comment: Change `/etc/hostname` to `localhost` and restart your system

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which worked for me.

First of all edit your `/etc/hostname`, write `namenode or alias you want to set for namenode` then run `sudo ifconfig eth0 down&&sudo ifconfig eth0 up` and try again.